# How to get / set caret position in silverlight textbox?

Tags: silverlight

How to get / set caret position in silverlight textbox ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TextBox.SelectionStart should work for you.
Setting TextBox.SelectionLength will define the length of the selected/highlighted text if you need it.